# c++ why are my statements in if loop not executing

Tags: c++, function, swap

I have a function that checks if a is more than b. My output is "ok", which means that the if statement is true but I don't understand why it doesn't swap a and b. (p is another variable in the function)

```
    if (a > b)
    {
        cout << "ok " << endl;
        swap(a, b);
        _bubbleUp(p);
    }
    else
        cout << "no " << endl;
```

My swap function

```
void swap(T a, T b)
{
    T temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Your swap function takes `a` and `b` by **value**, so it does not alter the passed variables.

In order for the change to propagate, you need to take the arguments by reference:

```
void swap(T& a, T& b)
{
  // ...
```

Or even better: just use `std::swap()` instead.

Comment: It's the same even when I use the the built-in swap function in C++ though. "ok" is printed but it's not going into the swap function.

Comment: @dumbodumbo "but it's not going into the swap function." You are making a big assumption here. "calling the function had no effect" also a possibility. You need to show us a full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

This line: `void swap(T a, T b)`

When the compiler sees that, it actually creates a copy of a and b, it did not change the actual value of a and b. That is pass by value

You have to pass by reference: `void swap(T& a, T& b)` or use the standard `std::swap()`